# Where is %% used in R?

Tags: r

I am beginner at R and learning about loops, I came across these two examples:

```
v <- LETTERS[1:4]
for ( i in v) {
  print(i)
}
```

```
x <- c("Hardwork","is","the","key","of","success")  
y="is"
if(y %in% x) {    
  print("key is found")  
} else {  
  print("key is not found")  
}
```

Here, I am not able to understand why we used %in% in the second example and "in" in the first example. I tried to use them the other way around but I got an error. How can this rule of using %in% be generalised?

Comment: `%in%` returns a logical vector, whereas `in` will be a for each value.  Note the use of `%in%` in `if` (which expects a logical input - TRUE/FALSE), where as `for` loop is iterative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### The '%' signs denote an infix operator

This is explained most quickly with an example. Most functions in R do something to something else. So `f(x)` is doing function `f()` to object `x`.

Infix operators are also functions, but they do something to two things. So `x %in% y` does `%in%` to `x` **and** `y`.

You can easily make your own infix operators, like so:

```r
x <- c(1,2,3)
y <- c(5,2,9,10)

## get the max value of each vector at each index
`%is_longer_than%` <- function(x,y){
  if(length(x) > length(y)) TRUE
  else FALSE
}

x %is_longer_than% y
#> [1] FALSE

y %is_longer_than% x
#> [1] TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

You can actually see that `%in%` is just a function in R by running `` `%in%` `` in the console:

```r
`%in%`
#> function (x, table) 
#> match(x, table, nomatch = 0L) > 0L
#> <bytecode: 0x00000226009335c0>
#> <environment: namespace:base>
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

So `x %in% y` is equivalent to `match(x, y, nomatch = 0L)`

#### `in` versus `%in%`

`in` and `%in%` are two completely different things. The '%' signs don't do something to `in`, they're just different functions with similar names. `in` is a reserved word in R, which does very secret things in C++. It's similar to other reserved words like `for` and `<`.